Stencil dispose store causes tests timeout
I have a very simple Stencil component:
export class MyApp{
  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        <h1>{state.projectName}</h1>
      </Host>
    );
  }
}

That uses a simple store:
const { state, dispose: disposeAppState } = createStore({
    projectName: null
});

export default state;
export { disposeAppState };

And this is my test:
describe('test', () => {
  afterEach(() => disposeAppState());

  it('should render title', async () => {
    const page = await newSpecPage({
          components: [MyApp],
          html: '<my-app></my-app>'
    });
    const host = page.body.querySelector('my-app');
    const title = host?.shadowRoot?.querySelector('h1')!;

    expect(title).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

But when running stencil test --spec --detectOpenHandles -- my-app.spec.tsx, I have the following error:
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  Timeout

       7 |
       8 | describe('test', () => {
    >  9 |   afterEach(() => disposeAppState());

How can I avoid that?
